# Add form data in list(dot net core)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to add the form data to the list and show it in a table through the controller to view but not able to access the values. I have made an Index file for form view student model class and studentrepo and istudentrepo which returns the list but how to add the form values in that list so they render.Below is my code

```
 private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IStudentRepository studentRepository)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _studentRepository = studentRepository;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {   
            return View();
        }
        
        public ActionResult StudentDetails()
        {
            var data = _studentRepository.GetStudents();
            return View(data);
        }
Student details - 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "StudentDetails";
}
@model List<DotNetdemo.Models.Student>
<div>
    <table id="tab" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">School</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                <th scope="col">Gender</th>
                <th scope="col">Standard</th>

            </tr>
            @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.name</td>
                    <td>@item.school</td>
                    <td>@item.address</td>
                    <td>@item.gender</td>
                    <td>@item.standard</td>
                </tr>
Index - 
@model DotNetdemo.Models.Student
<div class="card">
        <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="StudentDetails" method="post">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>REGISTRATION FORM</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-3">
            
            <label asp-for="name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input asp-for="name" class="form-control"/>
                <span style="color:red" id="username"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <label asp-for="school" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input asp-for="school" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you get the student list in StudentDetails() method on the controller side? while you run the project.
Also, try to use StudentList class instead of the direct Var data variable.

Comment: Yes, the dummy data in list is showing but how to extract values from form and then add to list

Comment: Hi @SanmeetSingh, any update? If my answer helps you, remember to accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string school { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string standard { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model Student

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="StudentDetails" method="post">
            <div class="heading">
                <h2>REGISTRATION FORM</h2>
            </div>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="school" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="school" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="school" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="address" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="gender" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="gender" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="gender" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="standard" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="standard" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="standard" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

StudentDetails.cshtml:

```
@model List<Student>
<div>
    <table id="tab" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">School</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                <th scope="col">Gender</th>
                <th scope="col">Standard</th>

            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.name</td>
                    <td>@item.school</td>
                    <td>@item.address</td>
                    <td>@item.gender</td>
                    <td>@item.standard</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Repo:

```
public interface IStudentRepository
{
    List<Student> GetStudents();
    Task CreateStudent(Student student);
}

public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
{
    private readonly YourDbcontext _context;
    public StudentRepository(YourDbcontext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task CreateStudent(Student student)
    {
        _context.Add(student);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        var students =  _context.Student.ToList();
        return students;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;
    public HomeController(IStudentRepository studentRepository, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> StudentDetails()
    {
        var data = _studentRepository.GetStudents();
        return View(data);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StudentDetails(Student student)
    {
        await _studentRepository.CreateStudent(student);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(StudentDetails));
    }
}
```